# Channel shape of NMOS in saturation

Tags: mosfet, saturation

According to the Sedra/Smith Microelectronic Circuits textbook, 6/7 eds.,  increasing \$v_{DS}\$ beyond \$v_{OV}\$ has no effect on the channel shape and charge.  Why is that?  It seems as if (thinking naively) increasing \$v_{DS}\$ should move the point at which the channel is pinched towards the source, thereby decreasing the charge in the channel.  Also, if \$v_{DS}\$ is large enough, wouldn't we have some sort of breakdown?

The textbook says further that any increase in v_{DS} above the saturation threshold appears as a voltage drop across the depletion region.  Why is that?

A related question: why is the bottom of the channel a straight line?

Comment: I actually remember that the channel becomes trapezoid from the same book, but cannot remember the condition for it

Answer (score 0):

Velocity saturation. Above 1 volt/micron (SWAG), the carriers are not accelerated any more.